# Cheapest SQL Statement possible / Are there Client-Side SQL Statements?

Tags: mysql, sql

Questions

1. What is/are the most cheapest SQL-Statment(s) (in terms of Processing Overhead/CPU Cycles).
2. Are there (this will most likely be DB-Client specific) any Statments that are evaluated directly by the client and even do not go to the database server?

The result doesn't matter, if an empty statement (which produces an SQL Error) is the cheapest OK, then this is good too. But I am more interested in non Error Responses.

Background:

I have an application that queries a lot of data from the DB. However I do not require this data. Sadly, I have no possibility to skip this query. But I have the possibility to change the SQL Query itself. So I am trying to find the cheapst SQL Statement to use, ideally it should not even go to the SQL Server and the SQL-Client Library should answer it. I will be using MySQL.

UPDATES (on comments):

Yes, it can be a No-Operation. It must be something I can pass as a regular SQL String to the mysql client library. Whatever that string could be, is the question. The goal is, that this Query then somehowreturns nothing, using the least Resources on the SQL Server as possible. But in idealcase the client itself will realize that this query doesnt even have to go to the server, like a version Check of the client library (OK I know this is no standard SQL then but maybe there is something I do not know about, a statement that will be "short circuited/answered" on the client itself).

Thanks very much!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "client side" statement for a database server - by definition. `select 1` should be the cheapest.

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you seeking something like a no-operation query? In MySQL you could use `SELECT 0` for that. It will return one row, immediately.

Comment: This `--` is comment and it returns no data. it consumes less cpus, networks and ram than `SELECT 1`

Comment: @InoSHeo, FYI, MySQL does not allow executing a statement consisting of nothing but a comment.

Comment: @BillKarwin after turning on `general_log`, I've executed `--` then `mysql_query()` successed and `--` was logged in general log. Did you mean this scenario? Sorry for bad English. (Actually, I didn't understand "consisting of nothing but a comment")

Comment: (off topic in respect of the development if this question, but...) 2. All sorts of things like sums, filters, and ordering/pagination *can* be evaluated 'client-side', although obviously not using SQL but rather with something like a bit of JavaScript acting upon a well formed array (or json encoded version thereof)

Comment: @InoSHeo, my mistake, I tested and find you are correct. I got an error when I tried to prepare and execute a "--" query using PDO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DO 0
```

> [DO executes the expressions but does not return any results.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/do.html) In most respects, DO is shorthand for SELECT expr, ..., but has the advantage that it is slightly faster when you do not care about the result.